# Mimicing the setup of an azure sql server database locally

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

We are having significant performance problems on azure. Various factors have made this difficult to examine precisely on azure itself. If the problems are in the performance of the code or of the database I would like to examine them by running locally. However it appears that the default configuration of our database on azure is different than it is locally, e.g. apparently an azure created database defaults to run with different configuration than my local database, e.g. the default on azure includes read committed snapshot as I understand, but that is not the default for a database I create in sql server. That means that performance issues are different for the two.

My question is how can I find all such discrepancies between the setup of the two and correct them so that when I find speed issues locally I will know they represent speed issues on azure. I am a sql server novice. I recognize that I cannot recreate "time to database" and "network time" issues that way, but I don't think those are what are killing us.

Comment: a WA SQL Database and a SQL Server DB are not quite the same, although they rely on the same technology underneath there are still some big differences , where a DB is a real SQL DB, the WASD is a TDS with a lilmited feature set. the closest you'll get is to do an export from the WASD and import it in your SQL Server local db, but you need to keep in mind the differences between the 2 platforms

Answer (score 0):

You might find my [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051311/sql-azure-premium-performance/20067673#20067673) useful. 
We had great advantages in implementing telemetry to gather information and use it later for analysis, to finally find out where and how you are spending your time interacting with SQL and therefore how to improve the query plans. Here is a link to the CAT blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/06/28/telemetry-basics-and-troubleshooting.aspx